# How can I make a Polymer element take up all vertical space on the page?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I'm working on a single-page Polymer app and I want to achieve a layout that takes up the entire browser window, without adding any scrollbars. I want the layout to look like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| Header / Toolbar                            |
+---------------------------------------------+
| Custom element 1             | Custom el 2  |
|                              |              |
| (width: 70%)                 | (width: 30%) |
|                              |              |
|                              |              |
|                              |              |
|                              |              |
+---------------------------------------------+
| Footer                                      |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

The header and footer elements have a fixed height (given in pixels). The two custom elements have an initial width (given in %) and are separated by a `core-splitter` element, so the user can change the proportion they take up.

**Goal**: I want the two custom elements to take up ALL the remaining height in the browser window *without* creating any scrollbars.

My approach currently looks as follows:

```
<body>
  <div vertical layout>
    <header-element></header-element>

    <div horizontal layout>
      <custom-element-1></custom-element-1>

      <core-splitter direction="right"></core-splitter>

      <custom-element-2></custom-element-2>
    </div>

    <footer-element></footer-element>
  </div>
</body>
```

I have tried to put the `flex` attribute on the `<div horizontal layout>`, but that doesn't seem to have any effect. My only working approach so far is installing a `window.onresize` handler that takes the `innerHeight` of the browser window, subtracts the height of the header and footer, and sets the remainder explicitly on the two elements as `max-height` and `min-height`. This seems rather like a hack to me and I would assume this is a pretty common use case, and that Polymer has a built-in system to achieve this, but I cannot find it.

How can I achieve this layout without having to manually resize the elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try this approach ?

```
<div id="div" vertical layout> 
  <header-element id="header_element"> Header</header-element>
  <div id="div1" horizontal layout flex>
    <custom-element-1 id="custom_element_1" flex three> Element 1 </custom-element-1>
    <custom-element-2 id="custom_element_2"> Element 2 </custom-element-2>
  </div>
  <footer-element id="footer_element"> Footer</footer-element>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't quite get you the 70/30% split. http://jsbin.com/natoqededosu/1/edit seems to be what the original poster is after.

Comment: Works for me, with @ebidel's suggestion.